# How to hide input on conditions in Formtastic?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin, formtastic

I inherited a project that is using ActiveAdmin with Formtastic in Rails. I have very little experience with either of these, but it seems simple enough to do simple tasks.

So, I have been tasked with adding a radio input, but hides the another input if the radio doesn't match a certain value.  I've search everywhere and can't seem to find anything on this.

Here is my form:

```
form do |f|
  f.inputs 'Book Details' do
    f.input :name, required: true
    f.input :has_subtitle, as: radio, required: true
    f.input :subtitle
  end
end
```

In this form, I need to only show :subtitle, if :has_subtitle is set to true/yes, otherwise they should not see the input (if it's visible it should also be required).

Is this possible to accomplish in Formtastic?

Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't sound like a formtastic/Active Admin issue.  It sounds like you want some javascript to hide a field when a radio button value changes.  You can add a data element to the radio button and some javascript to catch the change event and hide the other field.

Comment: What in formtastic gives me the ability to add javascript to an element?

Answer (score 1):

```
f.input :has_subtitle, as: radio, required: true, { data: { toggle: 'subtitle_input' }}
```

Then add javascript (this is coffeescript) to a separate file (eg form.js.coffee)

```
$(document).on 'ready page:load', ->
  $('[data-toggle]').on "change", ->
    $($(this).data('toggle')).toggle($(this).val() == 'show')
```

You may need to configure this some, depending on the value from the radio button

Then include it in application.js

```
# application.js
//= require form
```