# if condition in activeadmin to display textfield

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I'm using activeadmin for my application. I've a form called 'daily_transaction' in which a user inputs 'account_type'. If the user selects the value of 'account_type=credit', the I should display only credit textfield. Else a debit field has to be displayed.
[active admin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DMzjy.png)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33679618/how-to-hide-input-on-conditions-in-formtastic

Comment: Is it applicable for 'collections'?